# how can i update data in table using sqlite in obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

hii every one

can any one suggest me one good tutorial which shows update table in sqlite database

Answer (score 1):

Open your database with:

```
sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK;
```

To update a row:

```
@synchronized(sqlLock]) {
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE TABLE Set Text = ? where ID = '%@'",objectID] UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {     

        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledStatement))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);    
}
```